# Kendo UI Grid data bind to two table DB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, grid, large-data

I am trying to figure out two things. First, is it even possible. Second, am I on the correct path?
I am making an ASP.net Kendo UI Grid that just needs a very simple two table, inner join from an Entity Framework model. The issue is that one of the fields is incredibly large. It requires me to set the value to the json object size to max int value just to be able to return a single table result.

Because the resulting set is so large, I do not seem to be able to use a view model. It just returns a size limit error on that as well. Is there a way to return a very large dataset from two tables to a single Kendo UI grid? I have tried every suggestion from every existing answer on Stack Overflow and the Telerik forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really think that some user need information which cannot be handled by default json object size.

May be should load first 50-100 characters from that field to grid and if user click on cell load rest of the data.

Another way is using virtual scroll or paging.

If kendo model cant handle your field size, you can add columnt to each row with `view large data` button and open window with text field loaded from `db` on click.

Comment: It turned out that my issue was with how the Kendo Grid is bound to data. Binding the grid to a single table T worked. Then I just needed to do some magic to fill the column.  Thanks for the suggestions however. I may end up using these down the road.